# Is this twig code performance wise, fast enough?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

Could this be somewhat built in a better way than this ? I was thinking of for loop, could I add it one time and then asking through my code what happens if the element[1] == "why_iclei" ?? Or somehow to put it in a cleaner way ? Is this performance wise, fast enough ?

```
                    <li class="  ">
                    <a href="#">why iclei</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        {% for element in elements %}
                            {% if element[1] == "why_iclei" %}
                                {% if element[2] == 1 %}
                                    <li><a href="#">{{ element[0] }}</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">our work</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        {% for element in elements %}
                            {% if element[1] == "our_work" %}
                                {% if element[2] == 1 %}
                                    <li><a href="#">{{ element[0] }}</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

I have this exactly the same for loop around 20 times in my code. Could I put it somehow once and get all the needed values from it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your list items in one loop and in markup just output your variables

```
{% set icleiList = '' %}
{% set our_workList = '' %}
{% for element in elements %}
    {% if element[1] == "why_iclei" and element[2] == 1  %}
        {% set icleiList = icleiList ~ '<li><a href="#">' ~ element[0] ~'</a></li>' %}
    {% elseif element[1] == "our_work" and element[2] == 1 %}
        {% set our_workList = our_workList ~ '<li><a href="#">' ~ element[0] ~'</a></li>' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<li class="  ">
    <a href="#">why iclei</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        {{ icleiList|raw }}
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">our work</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        {{ our_workList|raw }}
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I am going to try your answer and then if everything works out, I am going to put your answer as my answer. 
Thanks M Khalid Junaid.

Comment: This really is not proper to have that much logic in a view. You should update the array in the controller and then pass it to the view.

Comment: Hey nerdlyist, thanks for the response. Could You argumentatively say why should I add this logic to the controller and not in the view ?